# How can I get computed elements of a table in a django queryset?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

I'm trying to use django's queryset API to emulate the following query:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(year FROM chosen_date) AS year, 
EXTRACT(month FROM chosen_date) AS month,
 date_paid IS NOT NULL as is_paid FROM 
    (SELECT (CASE WHEN date_due IS NULL THEN date_due ELSE date END) AS chosen_date,* FROM invoice_invoice) as t1;
```

The idea is mainly that in certain situations, I'd rather use the `date_due` column rather than the `date` column in some situations, but that , since `date_due` is optional, I sometimes have to use `date` as a fallback anyways, and create a computed column `chosen_date` to not have to change the rest of the queries.

Here was a first stab I did at emulating this, I was unable to really see how to properly due the null test with the base api so I went with `extra`:

```
if(use_date_due):
    sum_qs = sum_qs.extra(select={'chosen_date': 'CASE WHEN date_due IS NULL THEN date ELSE date_due END'})
else: 
    sum_qs = sum_qs.extra(select={'chosen_date':'date'})
sum_qs = sum_qs.extra(select={'year': 'EXTRACT(year FROM chosen_date)',
                              'month': 'EXTRACT(month FROM chosen_date)',
                              'is_paid':'date_paid IS NOT NULL'})
```

But the issue I'm having is when I run the second query, I get an error on how the `chosen_date` column doesn't exist. I've had similar errors later on when trying to use computed columns (like from within `annotate()` calls), but haven't found anything in the documentation about how computed columns differ from "base" ones. Does anyone have any insight on this?

(edited python code because previous version had an obvious logic flaw (forgot the else branch). still doesn't work)

Comment: I would keep it simple and use a raw query. It is what they are there for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer:**
If you create an aliased (or computed) column using `extra(select=...)`
then you cannot use the aliased column in a subsequent call to `filter()`.
Also, as you've discovered, you can't use the aliased column in later calls to
`extra(select=...)` or `extra(where=...)`.

**An attempt to explain why:**

For example:

```
qs = MyModel.objects.extra(select={'alias_col': 'title'})

#FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'alias_col' into field...
filter_qs = qs.filter(alias_col='Camembert')

#DatabaseError: column "alias_col" does not exist
extra_qs = qs.extra(select={'another_alias': 'alias_col'})
```

`filter_qs` will try to produce a query like:

```
SELECT (title) AS "alias_col", "myapp_mymodel"."title"
FROM "myapp_mymodel"
WHERE alias_col = "Camembert";
```

And `extra_qs` tries something like:

```
SELECT (title) AS "alias_col", (alias_col) AS "another_alias",
        "myapp_mymodel"."title"
FROM "myapp_mymodel";
```

Neither of those is valid SQL. In general, if you want to use a computed column's alias multiple times in the SELECT or WHERE clauses of query you actually need to compute it each time. This is why Roman Pekar's answer solves your specific problem - instead of trying to compute `chosen_date` once and then use it again later he computes it each time it's needed.

---

You mention Annotation/Aggregation in your question. You can use `filter()` on the aliases created by `annotate()` (so I'd be interested in seeing the similar errors you're talking about, it's been fairly robust in my experience). That's because when you try to filter on an alias created by annotate, the ORM recognizes what you're doing and replaces the alias with the computation that created it.

So as an example:

```
qs = MyModel.objects.annotate(alias_col=Max('id'))
qs = qs.filter(alias_col__gt=0)
```

Produces something like:

```
SELECT "myapp_mymodel"."id", "myapp_mymodel"."title",
        MAX("myapp_mymodel"."id") AS "alias_col"
FROM "myapp_mymodel"
GROUP BY "myapp_mymodel"."id", "myapp_mymodel"."title"
HAVING MAX("myapp_mymodel"."id") > 0;
```

Using "HAVING MAX alias_col > 0" wouldn't work.

---

I hope that's helpful. If there's anything I've explained badly let me know and I'll see if I can improve it.

Answer (score 3):

Well here're some workarounds

**1.** In your particular case you could do it with one extra:

```
if use_date_due:
    sum_qs = sum_qs.extra(select={
                          'year': 'EXTRACT(year FROM coalesce(date_due, date))',
                          'month': 'EXTRACT(month FROM coalesce(date_due, date))',
                          'is_paid':'date_paid IS NOT NULL'
                        })
```

**2.** It's also possible to use plain python to get data you need:

```
for x in sum_qs:
    chosen_date = x.date_due if use_date_due and x.date_due else x.date
    print chosen_date.year, chosen_date.month
```

or

```
[(y.year, y.month) for y in (x.date_due if use_date_due and x.date_due else x.date for x in sum_qs)]
```

**3.** In the SQL world this type of calculating new fields is usually done by uing subquery or [common table expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html). I like cte more because of it's readability. It could be like:

```
with cte1 as (
    select
        *, coalesce(date_due, date) as chosen_date
    from polls_invoice
)
select
    *,
    extract(year from chosen_date) as year,
    extract(month from chosen_date) as month,
    case when date_paid is not null then 1 else 0 end as is_paid
from cte1
```

you can also chain as many cte as you want:

```
with cte1 as (
    select
        *, coalesce(date_due, date) as chosen_date
    from polls_invoice
), cte2 as (
    select
        extract(year from chosen_date) as year,
        extract(month from chosen_date) as month,
        case when date_paid is not null then 1 else 0 end as is_paid
    from cte2
)
select
    year, month, sum(is_paid) as paid_count
from cte2
group by year, month
```

so in django you can use [raw query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-sql-queries) like:

```
Invoice.objects.raw('
     with cte1 as (
        select
            *, coalesce(date_due, date) as chosen_date
        from polls_invoice
    )
    select
        *,
        extract(year from chosen_date) as year,
        extract(month from chosen_date) as month,
        case when date_paid is not null then 1 else 0 end as is_paid
    from cte1')
```

and you will have Invoice objects with some additional properties.

**4.** Or you can simply substitute fields in your query with plain python

```
if use_date_due:
    chosen_date = 'coalesce(date_due, date)'
else: 
    chosen_date = 'date'

year = 'extract(year from {})'.format(chosen_date)
month = 'extract(month from {})'.format(chosen_date)
fields = {'year': year, 'month': month, 'is_paid':'date_paid is not null'}, 'chosen_date':chosen_date)
sum_qs = sum_qs.extra(select = fields)
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this work?:

```
from django.db import connection, transaction
cursor = connection.cursor()

sql = """
    SELECT 
        %s AS year, 
        %s AS month,
        date_paid IS NOT NULL as is_paid
    FROM (
        SELECT
            (CASE WHEN date_due IS NULL THEN date_due ELSE date END) AS chosen_date, *
        FROM
            invoice_invoice
    ) as t1;
    """ % (connection.ops.date_extract_sql('year', 'chosen_date'),
           connection.ops.date_extract_sql('month', 'chosen_date'))

# Data retrieval operation - no commit required
cursor.execute(sql)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

I think it's pretty save both CASE WHEN and IS NOT NULL are pretty db agnostic, at least I assume they are, since they are used in django test in raw format..

Answer (score 1):

You could add a property to your model definition and then do :

```
@property
def chosen_date(self):
    return self.due_date if self.due_date else self.date
```

This assumes you can always fallback to date.If you prefer you can catch a DoesNotExist exception on due_date and then check for the second one.

You access the property as you would anything else.

As for the other query, I wouldn't use SQL to extract the y/m/d from the date, just use

```
model_instance.chosen_date.year
```

chosen_date should be a python date object (if you're using DateField in the ORM and this field is in a model)

Comment: actually the reason I do that is because later on I do a sum aggregation based on the year and the month. In order to do that I need to call `values` with the values I want to group by... and I can't use the field lookups like `__year` in `values`.

Comment: Another thing is that what I use for `chosen_date` depends on the context : sometimes I use the `due_date` with the `date` fallback, sometimes just `date`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the raw sql. The raw() manager method can be used to perform raw SQL queries that return model instances.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-sql-queries