# Why can't I use Django's field lookups in a values call?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I feel like this is related to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269218/how-can-i-get-computed-elements-of-a-table-in-a-django-queryset/18269347?noredirect=1#18269347) I asked, but here goes:

I'm working with Django's querysets, and have some dates I work on. In my code right now I'm using an `extra` call to try and extract the year and the month from the date:

```
sum_qs = sum_qs.extra(select={'year': 'EXTRACT(year FROM date)', 'month': 'EXTRACT(month FROM date)','is_paid':'date_paid IS NOT NULL'})

sum_qs = sum_qs.values('client__name', 'subtotal_currency', 'is_paid','year', 'month')
```

However, I'm trying to get rid of that call to `extra`, as it seems a bit useless considering that django has field lookups on dates for years and months.

So instead I tried to do the following:

```
sum_qs = sum_qs.values('client__name', 'subtotal_currency', 'is_paid','date__year', 'date__month')
```

But here I get a bit of a bizarre error:

```
Join on field 'date' not permitted. Did you misspell 'year' for the lookup type?
```

Firstly I'm not really able to decipher what this error is supposed to mean. But also, is it really impossible for me to get the year out this way? I mainly want to do this because later on I `annotate` my queries with a Sum that sums together based off of the year and the month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values

I think you still need to use the extra query.

> **Field lookups**
>
> Field lookups are how you specify the meat of an SQL
> WHERE clause. They’re specified as keyword arguments to the QuerySet
> methods **filter(), exclude() and get()**.

Django thinks you are trying to look up a field on a relationship field "date" when you use the double underscore with your values query.

Answer (score 1):

`values` is used to limit the SELECT statement and will map values directly to db field names. Django's wizardry allowing you to use `date__year=2000` as a `filter()` call doesn't apply to `values()`.

The best answer really depends on your needs / if you need a queryset or values.. but most people use `values()` as a shortcut to receive a dictionary mapping of a small number of keys.

It's a shortcut that normally works! If it doesn't, don't hesitate to find any way to make the data work and move on..

```
[{'date__year': x.date.year, 'foo': 'bar'} for x in sum_qs.values('date', 'foo')]
```