# Speed up django nested for loop time series

Tags: python, django, performance, datetime, optimization

I am working on a django-based open source project called OpenREM (http://demo.openrem.org/openrem/, http://openrem.org).

To calculate data for one of the plots that are used I am carrying out a series of queries to obtain the number of items that fall into each of the 24 hours for each day of the week. This data is used to plot the pie chart of studies per weekday on the CT page of the demo site, with a drill-down to studies per hour for that day:

```
studiesPerHourInWeekdays = [[0 for x in range(24)] for x in range(7)]
for day in range(7):
    studyTimesOnThisWeekday = f.qs.filter(study_date__week_day=day+1).values('study_time')
    if studyTimesOnThisWeekday:
        for hour in range(24):
            try:
                studiesPerHourInWeekdays[day][hour] = studyTimesOnThisWeekday.filter(study_time__gte = str(hour)+':00').filter(study_time__lte = str(hour)+':59').values('study_time').count()
            except:
                studiesPerHourInWeekdays[day][hour] = 0
```

This takes a little while to run on a production system. I think the second FOR loop could be removed by using a qsstats-magic time_series, aggregated over hours. Unfortunately there isn't a suitable datetime object stored in the database that I can use for this.

Does anyone know how I can combine the "study_date" datetime.date object and "study_time" datetime.time object into a single datetime.datetime object for me to be able to run a qsstats-magic time_series by hour?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 1):

**If you can at all** (though you don't seem able given your circumstance) it would be best to change the database schema to reflect the kinds of queries you're making. A datetime field that had this information, some type of foreign key set up, etc.

You probably already know that, though, so **the practical answer to your question** is that you want to use the underlying database tools to your advantage through an [extra() call](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra). Maybe something like this* if you're using postgres:

```
date_hour_set = f.qs.extra(
    select={
        'date_hour': "study_date + interval '1h' * date_part('hour', study_time)",
        'date_hour_count': "count(study_date + interval '1h' * date_part('hour', study_time))"
    }).values('date_hour', 'date_hour_count').distinct()
```

which would give you queryset of datetimes (hours only) with their associated occurrence count. Handwritten SQL will give you the easiest option at the moment because of [Django's lagging TimeField support](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22316), and will probably be the most performant, too.

*Note I don't write SQL regularly and am being lazy, so there are cleaner ways to work this.

**If you really really need to be database portable and still can't edit the schema,** you can stack together features of Django aggregation that are maybe a little convoluted all together:

```
from django.db.models import Value, Count, ExpressionWrapper, CharField
from django.db.models.functions import Substr, Concat

hour_counts = f.qs.annotate(hour=Concat(Substr('study_time', 1, 2), Value(':00:00')))
date_hour_pairs = hour_counts.annotate(
        date_hour=ExpressionWrapper(Concat('study_date', 'hour'),
        output_field=CharField())).values('study_date', 'hour', 'date_hour')
date_hour_counts = date_hour_pairs.annotate(count=Count('date_hour')).distinct()
```

which should give you a set of dicts with a datetime.time object for 'hour', the datetime.date you started with for 'study_date', a concatted string version of the date and time under 'date_hour', and then the all important (date, hour) count under 'count'.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the suggestions. I'll try giving your last idea a go and report back on how it goes. I've also contacted the author of the project to see if they are open to the idea of adding an additional datetime field, as that would be the easiest solution for me.

Comment: I tested this out on a dummy app, so the basic structure should work, though I might have messed something up translating it into your project's context. Definitely say either way, though, because it was a fun puzzle to try to solve!

Comment: Actually noticed a problem with how I'd written it originally that would cause it to drop some data -- the date_hour_pairs line has to annotate before selecting values. Edited!

Comment: Hi. I've just tried to test the query out, but am having trouble with the import statements. I don't seem to have Value, ExpressionWrapper, Substr or Concat available to me. I've had a quick Google search to see if I can see why, but can't find a simple answer. Are you able to help? Thanks, David

Comment: What version of Django are you on? django.db.models.functions is new to 1.8, and so is ExpressionWrapper - not sure about Value. If you can't use 1.8 then you're in a *really* tough spot, though you might be able to argue for it since it's a long term support release.

Comment: It's Django 1.6. There's a plan for the project to move to version 1.7, but it sounds like that won't help. The project author has got back to me to say that adding a new datetime field to the database will be OK, so I think I'm going to take that route. Many thanks for your time and help with this. Regards, David

Comment: I've just tried using your suggestion of an `extra` query. Unfortunately this fails with a `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'date_hour' into field.`. The first part of the `extra` query works: `f.qs.extra(select={'date_hour': "study_date + interval '1h' * date_part('hour', study_time)"})`, but when I add the `.annotate(Count('date_hour'))` part then I receive the FieldError. It seems that `annotate` can't make use of the `date_hour` field that is created by the `extra` command.

Comment: Try adding the count into the extra function. Haven't messed with it much, but if you add another pair of items to the dict with key 'date_hour_count' and value 'count(date_hour)' that should work. Updated my solution as such. Might get weird with how Django handles implicit grouping and such. If it doesn't work I'll play with it.

Comment: Hi. I've tried your new suggestion - thanks for taking the time to help. Unfortunately I get an error when I try to access the `date_hour_count` that the `extra` is trying to create: `ProgrammingError: column "date_hour" does not exist
LINE 1: ..._part('hour', study_time)) AS "date_hour", (count(date_hour)...`

Comment: Are you running Postgres on the box you're testing on? You need a different variation on the SQL if you're using something else.

Comment: Yes, I'm running Postgres on the computer that I'm testing on.

Comment: Try splitting the two select statements into two parts? date_hour_no_count = f.qs.extra(select={'date_hour': 'date arithmetic thing'}) and then date_hour_set = date_hour_no_count.extra(select={'date_hour_count': 'count(date_hour)'}).values('date_hour', 'date_hour_count').distinct()

Comment: Hmm. That doesn't work either. It seems that you can't use created fields using `extra` for further queries. It looks like this is discussed in this posting a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269218/how-can-i-get-computed-elements-of-a-table-in-a-django-queryset

Comment: What they say in that posting makes sense. Try wrapping the whole date_hour definition (the study_date + interval...) in a count() function call and use that as the definition for date_hour_count. You should then still be able to use the values() call (that's in the Django documentation) and so that should give you all the pairings. I'm not sure if distinct() will work, though. If it doesn't, you'd need to inject the DISTINCT paramater into the SQL also. I'm also not a great SQL writer by any means, so you may want to ask someone more knowledgable for a clean way to do this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78047/discussion-between-r-phillip-castagna-and-david).